# Template function inside template class

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates, class-template

I have this code:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass {
public:
    template <class U>
    void foo() {
        U a;
        a.invoke();
    }
};
```

I want it in this form:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass {
public:
    template <class U>
    void foo();
};

template <class T> /* ????? */
void MyClass<T>::foo() {
    U a;
    a.invoke();
}
```

How can I do this? What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Why not just do the function decl inside the class decl (see http://codepad.org/wxaZOMYW)? You can't move the function decl out of the header anyway, so...

Comment: @hiobs: FWIW, you can move the declaration into a CPP file. That said, I've only done this once to do some hackery. In that case, knowing how to do this is essential.

Comment: Sometimes one must move the function definition outside of the class, after definition of dependencies needed by the function body. This happens when class A uses class B and B also uses A.  In that case you declare A and B, then define A and B methods.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Write this:

```
template <class T>
template <class U>
void MyClass<T>::foo() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: void MyClass<T>::foo<T>()...
thanks, I tried it before, but it doesn't work to me.. perhaps I had to do clean project.

Comment: @user1074367: No, I think it's as I say.

Comment: actually I wrote:
        template <class T>
        template <class U>
        void MyClass<T>::foo() {
         U a;
     a.invoke();
        }
and it works

Comment: @user1074367: Err... yes, that's what I say in the answer, non?

Comment: sorry, you are right, my mistake... I thought, you wrote MyClass<U>

Comment: @user1074367: I'm not saying `foo<U>`... hit the refresh button, maybe you're seeing an earlier edit :-)

Comment: I know this is old, but I can't find much more info on it... Is this a typical design that appears often or maybe hints at a bad design?

Comment: @mike: Member templates are a perfectly normal and common thing.