# Template function in template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

[Related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640390/template-function-inside-template-class)

Can't get the following to compile and I don't really understand why.

[Codebolt Code](https://godbolt.org/z/Fh7hGW)

Snippet here

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>



template<typename T>
class A
{
    using func_type = bool(int const&);

    template<func_type U, func_type X>
    [[using gnu:cold]]void example(std::vector<std::string>&&);
};


template <typename T>
template <typename A<T>::func_type U, typename A<T>::func_type X>
void A<T>::example(std::vector<std::string>&&)
{

}
```

Thank you

Comment: man this is some wacky template stuff. i'm not sure if something like this is possible, but even then, it's really overly-complicated. maybe if you could tell us what you want from these we could offer a better solution?

Comment: personally, i have always had trouble with declaring class member functions with templates outside of the classes. aside from overloading the "T" class template, i'm not sure this is the way to go, but maybe i just don't know enough.

Comment: Can't you move this line `using func_type = bool(int const&);` outside of the class? It will solve your issue.

Comment: @VahidNoormofidi  wouldn't really want to do it as it would pollute the namespace, that is including other stuff as well. I am trying to define a template function outside the class

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the `func_type` anywhere outside of your class. Then you should change it to

`using func_type = bool(*)(int const&);`

Remember that the syntax is similar to emplying `typedef` for function pointers.

Comment: Interesting. Now the only curiosity remaining is *why* this makes the code well-formed

Comment: As I said, `using` and `typedef` both are almost identical. For the `typedef` the usage is `typedef bool (*func_type)(int const&)` and you should comply with the typedef function pointer format.

Comment: What you said is immaterial. The original code fails irregardless of whether or not we use `typedef` or `using` to define the type as a function type. What matters is that it's defined as a *pointer*. You haven't explained **at all** why changing to a pointer fixes the error.

Comment: [`Array and function types may be written in a template declaration, but they are automatically replaced by pointer to object and pointer to function as appropriate.`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) so in theory it shouldn't make any difference? Clang and MSVC show the same behaviour so I don't think it's a bug

Comment: The code doesn't fail if you even use `typedef bool (* func_type)(int const&)` but writing it in `using func_type = bool(int const&)` is like writing `typedef bool func_type(int const&)` which honestly I don't know if any compiler accepts it.

Comment: Ah maybe the `in a declaration` bit is the key, doesn't apply in definitions? This works https://godbolt.org/z/AvNZpk

Comment: @AlanBirtles might it be because of some aggressive and weird inlining?

Comment: @AlanBirtles i see what you mean, so you suspect that it is only in declarations, but in definitions it is up to you to provide the correct type.

Comment: Maybe, seems odd though that it works when `A` isn't a template. It is possible that gcc, clang and MSVC all have the same bug